# Why is EF eager loading include not working as expected?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have this repository,

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> dbEntitySet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        this.context = context;
        this.dbEntitySet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return this.dbEntitySet;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(string include)
    {
        return this.dbEntitySet.Include(include);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(string[] includes)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
            this.dbEntitySet.Include(include);

        return this.dbEntitySet;
    }

    public void Create(TEntity model)
    {
        this.dbEntitySet.Add(model);
    }

    public void Update(TEntity model)
    {
        this.context.Entry<TEntity>(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity model)
    {
        this.context.Entry<TEntity>(model).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and the issue I have is with this method:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(string[] includes)
{
    foreach (var include in includes)
        this.dbEntitySet.Include(include);

    return this.dbEntitySet;
}
```

When I run it and put a breakpoint before the return, it is as if the **foreach** is being ignored.

the method above it works fine:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(string include)
{
    return this.dbEntitySet.Include(include);
}
```

To call it, I basically do this:

```
var a = this.Repository.GetAll(new string[] { "ForbiddenUsers", "ForbiddenGroups" }).ToList();
```

which pulls back the results but not does include the includes :D If I modify the call to:

```
var a = this.Repository.GetAll("ForbiddenUsers").ToList();
```

It works fine.

Can someone provide me with a resolution?

Comment: +1 for the GetAll method idea! Useful!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your method to look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(string[] includes)
{
    var query = this.dbEntitySet;

    foreach (var include in includes)
        query = query.Include(include);

    return query;
}
```

The `Include` method does not mutate the `DbSet`, it only returns you a new `DbQuery` with your include.

Comment: For the first one, I get an invalid cast exception, for the second one it errors out when I run it (it compiles fine). I am going to do a few more tests to see what the problem is

Comment: Yeah, the problem with your second method is that you the include thinks I am trying to create a navigation property with all the joined strings which just doesn't work

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought you might be able to do that but I guess I was mistaken. I've removed that second example.

Answer (score 1):

This code is incorrect:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(string[] includes)
{
    foreach (var include in includes)
       this.dbEntitySet.Include(include);

    return this.dbEntitySet;
}
```

The correct code is the following:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(string[] includes)
{
     IQueryable<T> query = this.dbEntitySet;

     foreach (var include in includes)
         query = query.Include(include);

    return query;
}
```

In your place I will use Lambda Expressions like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
     IQueryable<T> query = this.dbEntitySet;

     foreach (var include in includes)
         query = query.Include(include);

     return query;
}
```

Comment: Lambdas may not work here. `Expression<Func<T, TRet>>` is not convertible to `Expression<Func<T, object>>`, and I believe a cast in the lambda will throw off the magic.

Comment: @CoryNelson I never mentionned Expression<Func<T, TRet>>. Expression<Func<T, object>> work well for me. Where did you see that TRet in my code?

Comment: Indeed you did not mention it -- what I'm pointing out is that everyone's lambdas *will* be of some type -- not `object` -- so I don't see the usefulness of your method as expressions for `Func<T, int>` etc. are not convertible to expressions for `Func<T, object>`.

Comment: Did you test my code before talking about that? Maybe it's not work with your scenarios but it works well for me. 

You can check this example => http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2013/08/23/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: @CodeNotFound your first query has the same problem as mine. It seems to ignore the includes, although it does compile. Also, how would you call the second method??

Comment: @r3plica If you read my post i said that the firt query is incorrect. The second is the correct.
Not forget to use my last query beacuase it uses lambda expressions.

Comment: Hey @CodeNotFound Your second query is incorrect too, it should be query = query.Include(include);